# ¿Cómo mostar un dato dinámico de un switch en cardview dentro de un recyclerview a un textview de la actividad que los contiene?

Tags: android, recyclerview, textview, cardview

Resulta que tengo un componente switch de android dentro de un cardview que a su vez está en un recyclerview y necesito que cada vez que cambie de estado el switch se muestre dicho estado en un textview que esta fuera del recyclerview pero en la misma actividad.

Tengo entendido que no se puede hacer referencia a un componente que no pertenezca al mismo layout, pero no tengo idea de cómo pasar el dato. He probado con una clase java con su respectivo constructor, shared preferences pero los cambios no se reflejan apenas cambia el switch.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Sin código no podemos ayudarte. Solo decirte que esa suposición de que no se puede acceder a un control de otro layout no es cierta.

Comment: hola amigo @SuperG280. ¿alguna referencia de como realizar dicho acceso?

Comment: Podría, pero sin ver tu código solo sería eso: elucubrar. Dentro de una acitivity, en su layout puedes tener múltiples layouts, y a todos los componentes incluidos en esos layouts accedes de la misma forma `findViewById`. Pero sin ver el código de tu proyecto, a saber...